# built in method like pandas.sub() that does row wise subtraction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a simple method for doing row wise subtraction on a pandas df. The closest that I can find is df.shift(1) which only works on datetime. So if I have a dataframe

```
  df['col'] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Is there a built in method that will allow me do element wise subtraction so that it returns the following, by subtracting from every element the one on its left. The first element will stay as is.

```
 sd['col'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Is there an already existing method that does this or do I have to code it myself ?

Comment: Sorry your result doesn't match your problem description, please explain how you get from your starting column to your desired result

Comment: yeah sorry your right, updated it there

Comment: I still don't quite understand the output.  You only have 5 numbers to start with: how do you get 5 1s if you subtract neighbouring elements?  Shouldn't either the first or the last value be null?  Or if you want it to be filled with the nearest, which one do you want to fill?

Comment: First value is correct. The subsequent values are to be subtracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment you write

> First value is correct. The subsequent values are to be subtracted.

So, say you want to place the differences in a column called `diff`. Then you could do

```
df['diff'] = df['col'].diff()
```

(using [`pd.DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)), which would place the difference in every entry except the first. You can easily mend this with

```
df['diff'].values[0] = df['col'].values[0]
```